# Designing a low-level NPC mage

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, encounter-design, npc

So, I am working on a dungeon for a small party:

- (Tweaked) Drow Sorc2 -- good stats and a decent spell selection
- Human Rgr2 -- has a bit of healing, but more of a tanky/hack-and-slash type so far

and want to give them a small challenge in the form of an encounter with a solo, low-level mage.  However, the Mage in the MM Appendix B starts off at CR 6, with fifth level casting, and all of the lesser casters there are divine in nature.  Should I simply build a low-level wizard or sorcerer PC to use as a NPC, or what would be a good guide to making such a NPC from "whole cloth"?

Comment: Have you read through the DMG? What about its monster creation rules are unclear and/or don't meet your "guide to making such a NPC from "whole cloth"?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer "Does a guide to make NPCs exist" sounds a lot like a read-the-book question. Preceded by a "should I?" alternative question, there's a definite lack of indication of what problem we are supposed to solve.